# Get URLs lowest path by domain

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like the following...

```
$urls = array(
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://www.google.com/maps",
    "http://www.google.com/mail",
    "https://drive.google.com/help",
    "https://www.youtube.com",
    "https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions",
    "https://www.facebook.com/me",
    "https://www.facebook.com/me/friends"
);
```

I find this hard to explain but I want to break this array down to only show the lowest path for each domain with no duplicates, so it looks like this...

```
$urls = array(
    "http://www.google.com",
    "https://drive.google.com/help",
    "https://www.youtube.com",
    "https://www.facebook.com/me"
);
```

Comment: The question is understandable but you need to show what you have tried and where exactly are you stuck and/or what the error is.

Comment: Is the lowest path for a domain always before the other ones in the array?

Comment: @Barmar no, they can be in any order

Comment: Loop through the array, creating a new associative array whose key is the domain, and value is the shortest URL seen so far for that domain. When you're processing a new element of the array, test if it's shorter than the current element for that domain, and replace it if it is.

Comment: You already asked this question over here [reduce-url-strings-with-no-duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955966/reduce-url-strings-with-no-duplicates). And whats the question of asking the same question in different manner as you already had an answer over there

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by walking through the array and inspecting the `host` key by using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url). The following logic will give your desired result.

```
$output = array();

//Sort the array by character length
usort($urls, function($a, $b) {
   return strlen($a)-strlen($b);
});

array_walk($urls, function($url) use (&$output) {
   //Parse the URL to get its components
   $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
   //See if we've already added the host to our final array
   if( array_key_exists($parsed_url['host'], $output) === FALSE ) {
     //We haven't, so we can now add the url to our final array
     $output[$parsed_url['host']] = $url;
   }
});
```

https://eval.in/415655

Comment: The lowest path for a domain does not always come before the other ones in the array.

Comment: @itsliamoco I've just modified the code to sort the array by character length. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 $urls = array(
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://www.google.com/maps",
    "http://www.google.com/mail",
    "https://drive.google.com/help",
    "https://www.youtube.com",
    "https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions",
    "https://www.facebook.com/me",
    "https://www.facebook.com/me/friends"
);
$temp = array();
$res = array();
usort($urls, function($a, $b) {
   return strlen($a)-strlen($b);
});//sort the array based string length
foreach($urls as $url){
  $str = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $url);
  $strarray = explode("/", $str);
  if(!in_array($strarray[0], $temp)){
    $temp[] = $strarray[0];
    $res[] = $url;
  }
}
echo"<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo"</pre>";
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.google.com
    [1] => https://www.youtube.com
    [2] => https://www.facebook.com/me
    [3] => https://drive.google.com/help
)
```